# Why array is not full after initialization in constructor PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I have a two classes PHP:

1. Profile
2. Publicprofile

At `Publicprofile` class there are:

```
public function index($id){
        $profile = new profile($id, true);
        $profile->index();
}
```

So, here I create a new object **profile**.

Let's some to see class **Profile**:

```
class Profile extends Auth {

    public  $data = array();
        public function __construct($idUser = null, $view = false){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->getTemplate();
        }
    }
}
```

The function **getTemplate()**; - forms an array `$this->data`

If to show at once this array after execute *getTemplate()*, will see (via *var_dump*), that array contains data with a keys:

1. view_inside
2. view

When is called a method `$profile->index()` - this array not is same:

**Method index in class Profile:**

```
public function index(){
        var_dump($this->data); die(); // Here there are not keys view_inside, view
        $this->route();
    }
```

What is wrong at my code, that the source array in one class is different at two methods?

**Function GetTemplate():**

```
public function getTemplate(){

                $this->data['view_inside']   = 'profile/doctor/index';
                $this->data['view_left']     = 'profile/doctor/left';
                $this->data['view_edit']     = 'profile/doctor/personal_update'; 
                $this->data['view_personal'] = 'users/doctor/personal';
var_dump($this->data); // All right
}
```

Comment: Your first index function clashes and it'll result in a infinite loop, you're recalling the function with no parameter, so you'll receive an error & a time out

Comment: Can you share the content of `getTemplate()` ? Where did you try to var_dump when it still contains the values ?

Comment: If make `var_dump($this->data)` in the end of method `getTemplate()` I see array items: **view_inside**, **view**, I edited question and added function getTemplate()

Comment: May be the function `index()` calls constructor `Profile` again? Use **Codeigniter**

Comment: @Alice There is no reason for `index` to call the constructor by itself, really. I tried to re-create a similar code architecture, and it runs well. Do you see any difference with your code : http://codepad.org/63x2IpBN Did you try to remove `parent::__construct();` by any chance ?

Comment: In class **Profile** after call $this->template(); I made **var_dump($this->data)** and got:

`["view_inside"]=>
  string(20) "profile/index"
  ["view_left"]=>
  string(19) "profile/left"`, If do it at method `index() { var_dump();}` - array is wrong. Thank for example, but I can not understand what is reason...

Comment: @Alice I can't understand too. Maybe could you try to reproduce this weird behavior using http://codepag.org/ (Or any other code sharing website), so we can see where and why something is going wrong ?

Comment: Okay, thank you, I try himself, check all and will post here